# How do I add GCS credentials to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, kaggle, cloud-storage

I'm trying to train a model on kaggle and dump tensorboard logs into a GCS bucket. I'm hesitant to allow anonymous read/write on my project and would like to be able to have tensorflow use a custom service account with limited quotas for all GCP / gfile.GFile operations. Is there anyway to provide tensorflow with a service account json to use?

Is my best bet just security by obscurity?

Comment: "security by obscurity" is never a good idea. There are thousands of hackers running automated tools. What are you running Tensorflow on? If Compute Engine, this is very easy via the Compute Engine Default Service Account.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced using Kraggle and I do not really understand what limits do you want to apply on the service account, but you can follow the next steps to determine a service account access for Google Cloud Storage while using TensorFlow:

1. Follow [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/add_filesys) to implement GCS custom FileSystem in Tensorflow.
2. Check the [Python client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html) to instantiate the client.
3. The service account permissions required for storage are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/access-control#permissions_required_for_storage).
4. To grant roles to a service account, follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource).
5. Check the snippet in [Federico's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950943/credentials-error-when-using-google-transfer-service-to-transfer-file-from-aws-t?noredirect=1#comment86999085_49978173), based on [this documentation](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html), to implement the service account in your Python code.

Snippet:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have service account credentials in a json file, you can specify it in the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to have TensorFlow be able to read/write to GCS via `gs://` urls.

You can test it out in the following way, by running the following in bash (it downloads a smoke test script from TensorFlow's repository and runs it on your bucket url with your credentials):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/tools/gcs_test/python/gcs_smoke.py
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=my_credentials.json python gcs_smoke.py --gcs_bucket_url=gs://my_bucket/test_tf
```

This should create some dummy records in GCS and read from them. After this, you'd want to clean up the remaining temporary outputs to avoid further charges:

```
gsutil rm -r gs://my_bucket/test_tf
```